# Switch a workspace with one click

Tags: unity, workspaces, cinnamon

In Cinnamon the workspace switcher is a panel applet, which works as in the old times. One can click on the rectangle 1,2,3 to quickly choose the workspace.

[image: Workspace switcher]

In Unity one has to enter the workspace switcher (first click) and then select the workspace (second click). Is it possible to switch the workspace with one click as in Cinnamon?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `indicator-workspaces`, it is still two-click but it is much quicker in my opinion...

[image]

Installation :

```
sudo apt-get install python-wnck
wget -O indicator-workspaces_0.6.4_all.deb http://goo.gl/SG2dz
sudo dpkg -i indicator-workspaces_0.6.4_all.deb
```

---

You can also use shortcuts to quickly change between workspaces : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↑ ← → ↓</kbd>

Comment: Would it be technically, theoretically possible to patch the indicator to make it wider - showing all workspaces?